# Braintree Transaction

Tags: php, python, node.js, braintree

How can we process a transaction in Braintree using the credit card details (multiple card details are stored) in the Braintree? Will Braintree create a cardId for each credit card info?

Answer (score 4):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Each payment method added to the Braintree vault must have a unique token value, that can either be provided as a parameter to the relevant API call that creates the payment method, or automatically generated if such a value is not provided:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/#token